# How can I select all item at once using RxSwift operator?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

Let's say I have a table view to present products.

Here is my viewModel:

#### ProductViewModel.swift

```
var selectedObserver: AnyObserver<Product>
var state: Driver<Set<Product>>
var selectedSubject = PublishSubject<Product>()

self.selectedObserver = selectedSubject.asObserver()

self.state =
        selectedSubject.asObservable()
        .scan(Set()) { (acc: Set<Product>, item: Product) in
            var acc = acc
            if acc.contains(item) {
                acc.remove(item)
            } else {
                acc.insert(item)
            }
            return acc
        }
        .startWith(Set())
        .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: Set())

 self.isSelectedAll = Driver
        .combineLatest(
            self.state.map { $0.count },
            envelope.map { $0.products.count })
        .debug()
        .map { $0.0 == $0.1 }
```

As you see, every time I select an object, I will `scan` it into the state observable, so the cell can then observe the state change.

Here is the RxSwift binding between cell and viewModel:

#### ProductViewController.swift

```
self.viewModel.deliveries
        .drive(self.tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: DeliveryTableViewCellReusableIdentifier, cellType: DeliveryTableViewCell.self)) { (_, item, cell) in
            cell.bind(to: self.viewModel.state, as: item)
            cell.configureWith(product: item)
        }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

self.tableView.rx.modelSelected(Product.self)
        .asDriver()
        .drive(self.viewModel.selectedObserver)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

#### ProductCell.swift

```
func bind(to state: Driver<Set<Product>>, as item: Product) {
    state.map { $0.contains(item) }
    .drive(self.rx.isSelected)
    .disposed(by: rx.reuseBag)
}
```

Well, so far so good.

Now my question is how can I make a select all action e.g. tapping a select all button, so that all product will be somehow *`scan`* into states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, of course, more ways to do this. One that comes to my mind is having two different events for `single selection` vs. `select all`, unifying them in one enum, eg. `SelectionEvent`, merging them and passing that to the `scan` so that in the scan method you can differentiate between them.

Rough example, following your code:

```
var selectedObserver: AnyObserver<Product>
var state: Driver<Set<Product>>
var selectedSubject = PublishSubject<Product>()
var selectedAllSubject = PublishSubject<Product>() // Added
var selectedAllObserverObserver: AnyObserver<Void> // Added

self.selectedObserver = selectedSubject.asObserver()
self.selectedAllObserverObserver = selectedAllSubject.asObserver()

enum SelectionEvent {
    case product(Product)
    case all([Product])
}


self.state = Observable.of(
            selectedSubject.map { SelectionEvent.product($0) },
            // I figured envelope is observable containing all products.
            selectedAllSubject.withLatestFrom(envelope.map { $0.products }).map { SelectionEvent.all($0) }
        ).merge()
        .scan(Set()) { (acc: Set<Product>, event: SelectionEvent) in
            var acc = acc
            // now you can differentitate between events
            switch event {
            case .product:
                if acc.contains(item) {
                    acc.remove(item)
                } else {
                    acc.insert(item)
                }
            case .all(let all):
                acc = all
            }
            return acc
        }
        .startWith(Set())
        .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: Set())
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: So smart! Thank you.